# How to run at the same time tkinter app and thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I need to run tkinter applications(init_main() function) and at the same time an additional thread (translate function()) that could perform some actions. As I did, it only started the application.

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk 
from tkinter import ttk

WIDTH = "300"
HEIGHT = "150"
LANGUAGES = ("ru", "en")

def init_main(root):
    entry_text_box = tk.Text(root)
    entry_text_box.place(width=110, height=120, x=10, y=10)

    translate_text_box = tk.Text(root)
    translate_text_box.place(width=110, height=120, x=130, y=10)

    root.mainloop()

def translate(state):
    print("Translate function run")
    while state: 
        pass


if __name__=="__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Translator")    
    root.geometry(WIDTH + "x" + HEIGHT) 
    root.resizable(False, False)

    t1 = threading.Thread(target=init_main(root)) 
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=translate(1)) 
    t1.start() 
    t2.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to `thread` tkinter's mainloop. Also the correct syntax of `Thread` should be `Thread(target=function,args=(arg1,arg2,...))`

```
import threading
import tkinter as tk
import time

WIDTH = "300"
HEIGHT = "150"
LANGUAGES = ("ru", "en")

def translate(state):
    while 1:
        print("Translate function run")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__=="__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Translator")
    root.geometry(WIDTH + "x" + HEIGHT)
    root.resizable(False, False)

    t = threading.Thread(target=translate,args=(1,))
    t.start()

    entry_text_box = tk.Text(root)
    entry_text_box.place(width=110, height=120, x=10, y=10)

    translate_text_box = tk.Text(root)
    translate_text_box.place(width=110, height=120, x=130, y=10)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure they haven't fixed multithreading in python... what you are looking for is the after method. The tkinter after method. 
You can simply tell the application to run a function after a set amount of milliseconds.

```
root.after(10000, root.destroy)
```

or

```
root.after(1, translate)
```

multithreading can work, but it does not work well. It definitely doesn't scale. I know this doesn't allow you to pass your variable, but you will have to get creative with that.